# Replace MsTest with xUnit

Tags: visual-studio, mstest, xunit, xunit.net

While moving from MsTEst to xUnit VS2012 plugin I still can see my old MsTest in Test Explorer Window.

Does xUnit VS add on supports MsTest?

Does VS is able to work with 2 unit test providers in simultaneously?

Can I disable MsTest?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does xUnit VS add on supports MsTest?

> The xunit adapter will support only xunit. The xunit adapter will support only xunit.

Does VS is able to work with 2 unit test providers in simultaneously?

> Yes the UT extensibilty in VS supports as many adapters as you have provisioned on your VS machine

Can I disable MsTest?

> No clean/supported way of disabling mstest. The hack would be to remove the TMIAdapter.dll from your extensions folder.. remember this is not supported

Answer (score 1):

While VS has no problem at all with working with as much Unit Test providers as available, you should work with one and only one, albeit to keep your brain healthy in the long run ;-). MSTest and xUnit don't influence each other in any way - it's completely up to you to use one or the other.

If you want to get rid of the MSTest stuff, then the easiest thing for you to do is to simply unload the project(s) containing the MSTest tests and also close all tool windows that relate to MSTest (Don't try to 'hack' something or 'disable' MSTest! If you have bad luck you may destroy your entire VS installation!).

HTH Thomas